# Resizable search box, with image on the right

Tags: html, css

I want a resizable searchbox, like you all know it from e.g. FireFox
So I need an input box and a magnifying glass as button on the right side.

I have already made a test case for it:

http://jsfiddle.net/L8Wp3/61/

The thing is, the resizing doesn't work.
When I resize the whole page, then the input form should resize and the image should flow with it. But I have tried many things, the image will sometimes just break a line....

What I want to achieve is: I have two input tags(A & B) inside a div container, now B should flow to the right and A should take all the renaming space that is available.

How can I implement this in css?

Comment: I don't understand, do you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/L8Wp3/65/?

Comment: no definitely not, do you know the search box of FireFox? When you resize FF you will see that only the input box is resizing and the search button not. I want the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Give your searchbox (input text) a

resize:horizontal;
overflow:auto;

and for the max resize:

max-width: YYYpx;

Comment: Could you elaborate a little how it will make input box resizable?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand clearly your question but if you want to resize it,try to use  media query,with every different width of the div, you can  add exact width you want with your input, you can take an example how to create a search box simple here:

[Search box:](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/beautiful-css3-search-form)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. Take a look at the FireFox search box, when you resize the whole window, the search box shrink and the search icon flows with it. Thats what I want. When I set the width of the search box to e.g. 85% it will resize, but as you can see, at a certain size it will make a line break to the icon: http://jsfiddle.net/L8Wp3/68/

Comment: add an image is a best way to describe what you want!